# How to fix the content area got blocked by widget in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The Content area on my wordpress custom theme got blocked by widget sidebar so I can't click any thing on content area such as any smartphone products. For detail please check out [my website](http://galerigadget.com/).

**Here style.css:**

```
.widget {
    margin: 0 -6px 0.5em;
}

#secondary { /* Sidebar 1 */width: 20%;/* margin-top: -185%; *//* margin-left: 32%; */margin: 30px -68.3rem;
float: left;
position: relative;}

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 82%;
    margin-top: 107px;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 1170px;
    /* background-color: #FFFFFF; */
}
```

So how I can fix it? Thanks before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `id="wrapper"` from your sidebar.

Your sidebar should look like this:

```
...
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="not_wrapper">
        <div id="sidebanner"></div>
        <aside id="dc_jqaccordion_widget-2" class="widget ">...</aside>
...
```

Do notice, I substituted `id="wrapper"` with `id="not_wrapper"` for reference.